# How to draw the structure with rectangles inside

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-styles

I wish to draw the flow like in the picture using the code below, however, I found it is very hard to locate the rectangles by using Coordinate. Is there any better way to do this?

[image]

Here is the code I have tried:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-4,-4) rectangle (4,4);
\draw (-0.5,0)  rectangle (-3,-3);
\draw (0.5,0)   rectangle (3,-3);
\draw (-1,0)    rectangle (-2,-1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I’d work my way from the most inner to the most outer stuff, the `fit` library does help here. Instead of using `rectangle` paths, you’d be using rectangular nodes.

Comment: Have a look at the TikZ-uml package too http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en

Comment: Thanks, however, I never used fit before,can you give me an example?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This answer makes use of the following TikZ libraries:

- `shapes.geometric` for the `diamond` shapes
- `positioning` for the relative positioning of nodes ( `…=… of …`)
- `fit` for fitting nodes around other ones (`fit=(…)(…) …`)
- `calc` for the positioning of the diamond nodes

The node `f` is on the same height as `b` and `d`. The node `e` is on the same height as the left diamond (`dia1`).

The right big rectangles enclosing `e` and `f` uses the coordinate `dia1.north -| e` to fit, so that it has the same height as the other big rectangle.

Should the “plussed” diamond on the bottom be horiztonally centered between the big rectangles use

```
\node[dia cross] at ([yshift=-.5cm]$(left.south east)!.5!(right.south west)$) (dia2) {};
```

for the placement (notice the anchors `south east` and `south west`).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
    shapes.geometric,
    positioning,
    fit,
    calc
}
\tikzset{
    dia/.style={
        shape=diamond,
        minimum size=2em,
    },
    dia cross/.style={
        dia,
%       path picture={
%           \draw (path picture bounding box.west) -- (path picture bounding box.east)
%                 (path picture bounding box.north) -- (path picture bounding box.south);
%       },
        append after command={
            \pgfextra
                \draw[shorten >=\pgflinewidth,shorten <=\pgflinewidth]
                                   (\tikzlastnode.west) -- (\tikzlastnode.east);
                \draw[shorten >=\pgflinewidth,shorten <=\pgflinewidth]
                                 (\tikzlastnode.north) -- (\tikzlastnode.south);
            \endpgfextra
        }

    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.append style={draw,minimum width=3em,minimum height=1.5em},
    >=latex
]

%%% Left side
%% nodes with text
\node                (a) {a};
\node[below=.5 of a] (b) {b};

\node[right=of a]    (c) {c};
\node[below=.5 of c] (d) {d};

%% rectangles around nodes with text
\node[fit=(a)(b)] (ab) {};
\node[fit=(c)(d)] (cd) {};

%% top diamond
\node[dia] at ([yshift=.5cm]$(ab.north)!.5!(cd.north)$) (dia1) {};

%%% Right side
\node[right=2 of d] (f) {f};
\node[label={[inner sep=0pt,minimum height=2ex]above:h?}] at (f |- dia1) (e) {e};

% fake f to get the same spacing as on the left side (text with draw=gray)
\node[fit=(f),draw=none] (f') {}; 

%%% Big rectangles
\node[inner sep=1em,fit=(ab)(cd)(dia1)] (left) {};
\node[inner sep=1em,fit=(f')(dia1.north -| e)] (right) {};

%%% Diamond below
\node[dia cross] at ([yshift=-.5cm]$(left.south)!.5!(right.south)$) (dia2) {};

%%% Arrows
\foreach \pp/\pf/\pt in {--/a/b,
                         --/c/d,
                         --/e/f,
                         -|/dia1/ab,
                         -|/dia1/cd,
                         |-/left/dia2,
                         |-/right/dia2}
\draw[
    shorten >=\pgflinewidth,
    ->
] (\pf) \pp (\pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, however, it says "I can not find the file tizlibrary.\pgf@temp->shapes.geometric" when I run the code. Is it because I miss to install something?

Comment: @sweetyBaby Apparently. Though `shapes.geometric` is a part of TikZ it should be available if TikZ is available. Do you have an updated installation? TikZ’ current version is 2.10.

Comment: it is the latest one. And now a new problem occured when running the code, it says  "package pdfkeys error: I don not know the key /tikz/path picture"

Comment: @sweetyBaby Have you checked with [`\listfiles`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq) whether you have the right version? It does not seem to be the current version.

Comment: Thanks, finally, I have updated, however, the code still can not run successfully, the error says "PDFTexify failed to create a pdf file ". is there any possible to draw the picture using tikz 2.0?

Comment: @sweetyBaby That looks like a generic error message from your editor that of TeX. Anyway, you could try to compile this example without the `path picture` and instead use either `append after command` (see updated answer) or just draw the cross yourself.